# Data written to /dev/pts/x inside SIGINT (Ctrl+C) handler is randomly discarded

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, signals

Have `Archlinux64` on `VirtualBox`.

If I declare a SIGINT trap like this:

```
trap 'echo x' INT
```

inside an `ssh` session (running `bash`) and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> multiple times, only a few times does something appear in the terminal. Here's a more complex example. After pressing Ctrl-c 21 times:

```
[il@vmarch ~]$ n=0; trap 'echo " $n'\’'th INT"; n=$((n+1))' INT
[il@vmarch ~]$ ^C 0’th INT

[il@vmarch ~]$ ^C 7’th INT

[il@vmarch ~]$ ^C 8’th INT

[il@vmarch ~]$ ^C 9’th INT

[il@vmarch ~]$ ^C 18’th INT

[il@vmarch ~]$ ^C 21’th INT
```

Only pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> has this effect; if I send `SIGINT` explicitly (via `kill`), I get all the messages I am expecting. Reproducible in multiple terminal emulators. Never occurs in text console (`/dev/tty1`). Similar symptoms in `zsh` and `dash`: in zsh the results are pretty much the same. In dash the trap does not work, but without it the newline and the prompt are discarded as well.

Doing nothing for 5-10 seconds before pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> increases the chance of data being discarded.

```
$ uname -a
Linux vmarch.lan 4.0.4-2-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri May 22 03:05:23 UTC 2015 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Your question is a little unclear.  You show “0’th INT” and “7’th INT”; did you type Ctrl+C six times between them?  (They’re not shown.)  Also, you say “Similar symptoms in `zsh` and `dash`.”  Are they *similar*, or *the same*?  (I wouldn’t expect the results to be identical, since you said that the problem is “random”.)  If symptoms in `zsh` and `dash` are not the same as in `bash`, what are they?

Comment: @G-Man added more details